# Multiple overlayed images in the Navigation bar title

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uinavigationbar, uistackview

I know how to center a single image in `UINavigationBar` but no idea how to do that with dynamic number of images. I have a chat app that supports group chats. The number of people in a group chat could be as little as 3 but there's no upper limit.

In the `UINavigationBar`, I have to set the title to show at least 4 or 5 overlayed images (but not more than that since it looks odd in the `UINavigationBar`) and a `UILabel` showing how many more users are in the same group chat (ie `+ 15 more`). The title (all the images and the label) should be centered in the `UINavigationBar`. The images are being downloaded from the server.

When the user taps on the title (any of the images or the label in the `UINavigationBar`) it should trigger an action to show a full list of the users in a separate `UIViewController`

The number of the overlayed images is dynamic (based on each group chat) but I can't figure out how to do this. Here's what the image of what the end result should look like:

[image]

Has anyone done this before or have an idea how to accomplish this? Help is very much appreciated

**UPDATE:**

I've tried to accomplish this with `UIStackView` but I have multiple problems. Here's the code:

```
    var navStackView : UIStackView = {
    let stack = UIStackView()
    stack.axis = .horizontal
    stack.backgroundColor = .red
    stack.alignment = .fill
    stack.distribution = .fillEqually
    stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return stack
}()

var images = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let navController = navigationController!

    navController.navigationBar.addSubview(navStackView)
    // x, y, w, h
    navStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navController.navigationBar.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    navStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navController.navigationBar.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    navStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navController.navigationBar.topAnchor).isActive = true
    navStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navController.navigationBar.bottomAnchor).isActive = true


    for image in images {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: image)
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.bounds.height / 2
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
     //   imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
        navStackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)

        navStackView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }


    navigationItem.titleView = navStackView
}
```

Here's the result so far (I'm stuck though, not sure how to accomplish it): 
    [image]

Comment: Have you looked into `UIStackView`?

Comment: @Malik crossed my mind but never done this and I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: One way would be render a custom UIView on `titleView` of `navigationItem`

Comment: @kathayatnk trying to do that with `UIStackView` (updated the code above) but I have some issues with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out finally. Not sure if this is the right way to accomplish it, but it's a way to accomplish it and it works great. The thing to notice - I have to calculate the `navStackView` width based on the number of images we have. More than 5-6 images gets too crouded, so, no more than 5 images.

The `navStackView.spacing` also is calculated based the width and the space you'd like between the images.

```
var navStackView : UIStackView = {
    let stack = UIStackView()
    stack.axis = .horizontal
    stack.alignment = .fill
    stack.distribution = .fillEqually
    stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return stack
}()

var moreLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "+ 5 more"
    label.textColor = .black
    label.textAlignment = .left
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

var images = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "3",  "3"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let navController = navigationController!

    navController.navigationBar.addSubview(navStackView)
    // x, y, w, h
    navStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 95).isActive = true
    navStackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navController.navigationBar.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    navStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true
    navStackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navController.navigationBar.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

    // image height = 35, image width = 35
    // when subtracting spacing from NavStackView, we need to subtrack from the width as well for (items - 1)

    switch images.count {
    case 0:
        print("0 images")
    case 1:
        changeNavStackWidth(constant: 60, spacing: 0)
        moreLabel.isHidden = true
    case 2:
        changeNavStackWidth(constant: 80, spacing: 10)
        moreLabel.isHidden = true
    case 3:
        changeNavStackWidth(constant: 95, spacing: -5)
        moreLabel.isHidden = true
    case 4:
        changeNavStackWidth(constant: 110, spacing: -10)
        moreLabel.isHidden = true
    case 5:
        changeNavStackWidth(constant: 95, spacing: -20)
        moreLabel.isHidden = true
    case 6...1000:
        changeNavStackWidth(constant: 95, spacing: -20)
        moreLabel.isHidden = false
    default:
        print("default")
    }


    for image in images {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: image)
        imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true

        navStackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
        navStackView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    navController.navigationBar.addSubview(moreLabel)

    // x, y ,w, h
    moreLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navStackView.trailingAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
    moreLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navStackView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    moreLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navStackView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    navigationItem.titleView = navStackView

    let stackTap = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    stackTap.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stackTapped))
    navStackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    navStackView.addGestureRecognizer(stackTap)
}

@objc func stackTapped() {
    print("tapp")
}

func changeNavStackWidth(constant: CGFloat, spacing: CGFloat) {
    navStackView.constraints.forEach { constraint in
        if constraint.firstAttribute == .width {
            constraint.constant = constant
        }
    }
    navStackView.spacing = spacing
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    navStackView.subviews.forEach { $0.layer.cornerRadius = $0.frame.height / 2 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about stackView. But for a simple implementation I've used collectionView. Check the below strategy. You should be able to modify accordingly per your requirement.

```
    import UIKit


class OverlayCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    func didplay(with number: String) {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40.0, height: 40.0))
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
        view.layer.masksToBounds = true

        view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        view.layer.borderWidth = 2.0

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 2, y: 2, width: view.bounds.width - 4, height: view.bounds.height - 4))
        label.textColor = .white
        label.text = number
        label.textAlignment = .center

        view.addSubview(label)
        contentView.addSubview(view)
        contentView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
    }
}



class OverlayedView: UIView {

    var mainView: UIView!
    var imageCollection: UICollectionView!

    //Static for now
    let cellWidth: CGFloat = 40.0
    let cellHeight: CGFloat = 40.0
    var collectionWidth: CGFloat = 115.0

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        loadNib()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        loadNib()
    }

    private func loadNib() {
        if let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("OverlayedView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? UIView {
            mainView = view
            mainView.frame = self.bounds
            self.backgroundColor = .black
            addSubview(view)
        }
    }


    var dataSource = ["4","3","2","1"]

    func loadData() {

    //dynamically calculate collectionWidth to be able to kepp it in center
        collectionWidth = dataSource.count >= 4 ? CGFloat(dataSource.count) * cellWidth -  CGFloat((dataSource.count - 1) * 15) : CGFloat(dataSource.count) * cellWidth - CGFloat((dataSource.count - 1) * 15)  //CGFloat(dataSource.count * 15) here is the item spacing from delegate -15 inward so that we can get overlapping effect


        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        imageCollection = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: collectionWidth, height: self.bounds.height), collectionViewLayout: layout)
        imageCollection.center = mainView.center

        imageCollection.register(OverlayCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        //flip the collectionView so that it loads from right to left for overlapping effect
        imageCollection.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)

        imageCollection.delegate = self
        imageCollection.dataSource = self

        mainView.addSubview(imageCollection)
}

 }


extension OverlayedView: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if dataSource.count > 4 {
            return 4
        }
        return dataSource.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! OverlayCell
       cell.didplay(with: dataSource[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let size = CGSize(width: 40.0 , height: 40.0)
        return size
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0.0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return -15.0
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let navOverlay = OverlayedView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250.0, height: 44.0))
    navOverlay.loadData() . //pass your data to this method
    navigationItem.titleView = navOverlay
```

Comment: I've never heard or seen `UICollectionView` to be used in the navigation bar.